# Keep control on the same dialog in msi when user clicks on Ok

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

I am creating a DLL custom action which is showing a message box taking the values from the property table as below:

```
MessageBox(NULL, "This is a message box", szBuffer1, MB_OK);
```

I have attached this custom action to Next button. This will pop up a message box when `Next` is clicked on that dialog. When the user clicks on `Ok` button on the message box, the control should return to the same dialog and the next dialog shouldn't be displayed. How should I achieve this?

Comment: How is this related to Delphi?

Comment: delphi got tagged by mistake...but any answer on this?

Comment: I've removed the [delphi] tag

Comment: I tried to clean up the question but I still do not get it. You really have to clarify.

Comment: I am creating an msi in which there is one dialog. It has a next button. When user clicks on this I am executing a custom action which calls a function from stored dll. In that function I have created a messagebox as shown above with an "Ok" button. Consider it is an error message box. When this box pops up at run time and user clicks on "ok" button I want to return some value from that function which will keep the control on the same dialog. This action should repeat for every time user clicks on next button and there is an error in his entered values.

Comment: You should not display windows from Custom Actions, use the native MSI dialog boxes. The best solution to it is to use `SpawnDialog` as [shown in vinay's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163176/keep-control-on-the-same-dialog-in-msi-when-user-clicks-on-ok/8166985#8166985). Not to display secondary dialog boxes would be even better: collect data from the user step-by-step in the setup wizard. Additionally, *Next* button is supposed to move user to the *next* step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest you to use "SpawnDialog" of the WIX that will return control to the same dialog:
Here is the example:
1. Create a message dialog:

```
  <Dialog Id="MessageDlg" Width="260" Height="120" Title="[ProductName]">
    <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="102" Y="90" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="OK">
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Text" Type="Text" X="48" Y="22" Width="194" Height="60" Text="[YOURMESSAGE]" />
    <Control Id="Icon" Type="Icon" X="15" Y="15" Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Information icon" FixedSize="yes" IconSize="32" Text="WixUI_Ico_Info" />
  </Dialog>
```

2. Set the property "YOURMESSAGE" in the custom action.
3. Call this dialog on click of next button.

```
<Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="MessageDlg">1</Publish>
```

Comment: Additionally, publish event that starts new dialog box, the *next* one, should be conditioned. And the condition should be mutually exclusive with the spawned error dialog, so either error is shown or the user is moved to the next dialog in the wizard.

Comment: I liked your idea Alexey. Thanks!!

Comment: I got solution for this from somewhere else as: I made a custom Action "MyCustomAction" which checked if name already exists in IIS. If Yes then [TESTPROP] = "1" and No then [TESTPROP] = "0".

Then I added the following events on the Next button.

Event Argument Condition
DoAction MyCustomAction 1
[GOODPROP] [TESTPROP] 1
NewDialog _MyNextDialog [GOODPROP] = "0"
When the name exists I want to show some text.
I added the Actions Show and Hide on the Conditions table of the label with the conditions [GOODPROP] = "0" & [GOODPROP] = "1".